# WPF Outputting a response from the command line,GUI microcontroller

Tags: c#, user-interface, cmd, microcontroller

No response from the command line is displayed when JLink.exe starts, nothing happens when the "ReadMemory" button is pressed.
But if after that you enter the command "exit" all the operations performed on the command line are displayed.
How can you fix this and why is it happening?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Process jLinkProcess = new Process();
        
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            jLinkProcess.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files\SEGGER\JLink\JLink.exe");
            jLinkProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            jLinkProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            jLinkProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            jLinkProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            jLinkProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            jLinkProcess.OutputDataReceived += CmdProcess_OutputDataReceived;
            jLinkProcess.ErrorDataReceived += CmdProcess_ErrorDataReceived;
            jLinkProcess.Start();
            jLinkProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
            jLinkProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
            jLinkProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("connect");
            jLinkProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("NRF52811_XXAA");
            jLinkProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("SWD");
            jLinkProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("4000");
        }

        private void CmdProcess_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                TextBox2.Text += e.Data + "\r\n";
                TextBox2.ScrollToEnd();
            });
        }

        private void CmdProcess_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                TextBox2.Text += e.Data + "\r\n";
                TextBox2.ScrollToEnd();
            });
        }

        private void TextBox1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is TextBox textBox && e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                jLinkProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(textBox.Text);
                textBox.Text = string.Empty;
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        private void ReadMemory(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string mac = "mem 10000060,8";
            jLinkProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(mac);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Without any knowledge in WPF, this looks like a common buffering issue. The called application prints its messages, but on of the intermediate tiers buffers them, and only when the process finishes, all it flushed. Did you look up the documentation how to change the buffering for redirected `stdout`?

Comment: @thebusybee Sorry for late answer. Do you mean this documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.clipboard?view=windowsdesktop-5.0  .I have also tried these commands, but it didn’t work. jLinkProcess.StartInfo.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
 jLinkProcess.StandardOutput.BaseStream.Flush();

Comment: @thebusybee How is the buffer problem usually solved?

Comment: Oh, I have no idea how to do this with WPF. Perhaps some experts comes along...